# Scala dropWhile vs filter

Tags: scala, filter, functional-programming, iterator

```
val xs = Iterator
  .from(1)
  .dropWhile(_ % 2 != 0)
  .takeWhile(_ < 10)
  .toList
val ys = Iterator
  .from(1)
  .filter(_ % 2 == 0)
  .takeWhile(_ < 10)
  .toList
println(xs)
println(ys)
```

**Output:**

```
List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
List(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Why? I was expecting the same output from both.

Comment: `dropWhile` is the negated version of `takeWhile` (thus the similar names), not of `filter`.

Comment: @sepp2k I don't understand how your comment explains the output above. "dropWhile is the negated version of takeWhile" - ok, so?

Comment: Your second version differs in two ways from the first: You're using `filter` instead of `dropWhile` and you negated the condition you pass to it. You say you expect both versions to act the same, so it seems to me that you think `dropWhile` acts like `filter`, but with a negated condition (and therefore if you'd get the same results from both if you negate the condition). But it doesn't act like `filter` with a negated condition - it acts like `takeWhile` with a negated condition. If you replace `filter` with `takeWhile` in the second version, that will act the same as the first version.

Comment: @sepp2k "it acts like `takeWhile` with a negated condition" - but it does't appear to be doing anything in this case. Let me ask this way - how'd you get the same output as the 2nd one using only  `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`?

Comment: Sure, it does something: it drops the 1. "how'd you get the same output as the 2nd one using only takeWhile and dropWhile? " I wouldn't. `takeWhile`/`dropWhile` and `filter`/`filterNot` do different things and you use the one whose behavior you want in the current situation. You can't really imitate one's behavior with the other and why would you want to when you can just use the one you want in the first place?

Comment: I understand now. Tim's answer is little clearer so i'm gonna go with that one, but I upvoted your comment; besides, you didn't post an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dropWhile` discards all the items *at the start of a collection* for which the condition is `true`. It stops discarding as soon as the first item fails the condition.

`filter` discards all the items *throughout the collection* where the condition is not true. It does not stop until the end of the collection.

In your case, `dropWhile` drops `1` but stops when it reaches `2` because the condition `_ % 2 != 0` is false.

`filter`, on the other hand, drops all the values for which `_ % 2 == 0` is false, which is all the odd values.

Comment: I see. Now the Scaladoc makes sense too: _`dropWhile` - Skips longest sequence of elements of this iterator which satisfy given predicate p_. So, like @sepp2k said, it's not possible to get the 2nd output using only `*While` constructs.

Comment: I wonder what scenarios we need to use dropWhile instead of filter.