# Java Stream - what is the difference between filter() and dropWhile()

Tags: java, java-stream

With Java 9 method `dropWhile()` was added to the Stream API. When I read the documentation, I found out that it is very similar to Java 8 `filter()` method.

Am I missing something? What is the difference between these methods?

Comment: `dropWhile` only skips a continuous prefix of matches. `filter` drops any mismatched element.

Comment: Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850689/how-is-takewhile-different-from-filter) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583361/scala-dropwhile-vs-filter)

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at this example:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 1)
       .dropWhile(i -> i < 2)
       .forEach(System.out::println);

System.out.println("====");

Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 1)
       .filter(i -> i < 2)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

which will give the following output:

```
2
3
1
====
1
1
```

Firstly, in ordered streams `dropWhile` drops only the longest prefix of matching elements (see the docs). Also, you can see that `filter` specifies which elements need to pass, while `dropWhile` which to remove.

Answer (score 2):

[`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) - is a ***stateless*** intermediate operation which always returns a stream consisting only of elements the matches the given predicate.

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match
> the given predicate.

[`dropWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) -  is a ***statefull*** intermediate operation, which also expects a predicate and basically acts like a stateful filter. After the first element which doesn't match the predicate has been encountered, `dropWhile()` stops discarding elements from the stream.

> If this stream is **ordered** then the longest prefix is a contiguous
> sequence of elements of this stream that match the given predicate.
>
> If this stream is **unordered**, and some (but not all) elements of
> this stream match the given predicate, then the behavior of this
> operation is **nondeterministic**; it is free to drop **any subset**
> of matching elements (which includes the empty set).

To understand the difference between in behavior of the `dropWhile` with *ordered* and *unordered* stream, let's consider the following examples.

That would an example of *unordered* stream:

```
Set<Integer> numbers = Set.of(9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

numbers.stream()
    .dropWhile(i -> i < 9)
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Output can be for example `912`, it would range from `9` to `123456789` (meaning that **all** elements might be present, the order in the output would be unpredictable). Because the stream is unordered elements from the source might appear in the stream, and `dropWhile()` can be switched off at any point of execution, that's what the phrase *"behavior is nondeterministic"* in this case means.

Now let's take a look at the *ordered stream*:

```
List<Integer> numbers = List.of(9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    
numbers.stream()
    .dropWhile(i -> i < 9)
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

*Output:*

```
912345678
```

Since `9`, the very first element in the stream, doesn't match the predicate, it will never be evaluated again, `dropWhile()` is being switched off and all element would reach the terminal operation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small program that shows the difference.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = List.of(-1, -3, -4, 2, 5, -6, -7, 8);

        // Prints: 2, 5, 8
        System.out.println(numbers.stream()
                .filter(n -> n >= 0)
                .map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

        // Prints: 2, 5, -6, -7, 8
        System.out.println(numbers.stream()
                .dropWhile(n -> n < 0)
                .map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
    }
}
```

`filter` removes all the elements from the stream which do not match the predicate (in this case: `n -> n >= 0`, so it removes the negative numbers).

`dropWhile` removes the elements that *do* match the predicate (in this case: `n -> n < 0`), until it finds an element that does *not* match the predicate. From that point on it lets all elements pass through.

Note that the predicates used for `filter` and `dropWhile` are each others' opposites in this example.